# can't install any atom packages with npm error

Tags: npm, atom-editor, apm

unable to install any packages on atom. The error is

```
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yaoli/.atom/.apm/_logs/2020-02-17T09_39_31_164Z-debug.log
```

I have tried to clean the npm cached and reinstall npm. It didn't work.

Comment: Npm is installed Globally ?

Comment: Just default setting

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by deleting the contents of ~/.atom/.apm and then reinstalling the package through the atom gui.

```
~/.atom/.apm$ rm -rf *
```